# Python progress bar makes script unresponsive

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a progress bar that when I update it in a loop, the GUI becomes unresponsive.  Code:

```
def popup_progress(self):
    self.popup = T.Toplevel(self)
    ttk.Label(self.popup, textvariable=self.pop_label).grid()
    self.pgss = ttk.Progressbar(self.popup, mode='indeterminate')
    self.pgss.grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.update()
```

```
def get_paths(path, fldr):
    self.pgss['value'] += 1
    self.pgss.update()
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
        for entry in it:
            try:
                if entry.name == fldr:
                    folder.append(entry.path)
                elif entry.is_dir():
                    get_paths(entry.path, fldr)
            except OSError:
                continue
        return folder
```

```
self.popup_progress()
print(get_paths('C:\\', 'Downloads'))
self.popup.destroy()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While the `for` loop is running, `tkinter` isn't being updated. You have 2 options: Move the for loop in another thread, or add `self.popup.update()` somewhere inside the `for` loop. The first approach is better but the second one is easier to implement (but might not work)

Comment: Thanks, @TheLizzard.  But what I meant to say in my OP is that the `for` loop doesn't process.  It's like it freezes processing of the script and what the `for` loop is supposed to do doesn't happen.  I just get the progress bar popup and nothing else happens in the script.  Let me try your suggestions first before I call it incorrect...

Comment: What were you expecting to get? You create a window with the progressbar and then you add 1% on the progressbar. After that you do some stuff with files/folders.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and neither one works.  The progress bar pops up and the script just gets stuck with the progress bar open.  I have to close the script after that.

Comment: After `self.pgss.update()` try adding `return None`. It is just to test if the problem is inside the `with` statement/`for` loop.

Comment: Without the progress bar, the script works fine.  It's only when I add the progress bar in does it mess up.

Comment: Don't want to flood the comments, but I think I may have figured it out.  It had to do with setting `self.pgss['value'] += 1` inside the function.